# Regulate 0-6V output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I need to control output from 0-6V at max 1A (~0.8A).

Looking at the [datasheet for LM25010](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm25010.pdf) it looks I could control R1 and R2 feedback resistors and achieve just that.

Is it possible to get that range?
What information inside datasheet says how close I can get to Vin at Vout?

Comment: You have a bigger challenge at the low end, because it compares an attenuated version of the output voltage to its internal 2.5V reference. To regulate down to 0V you'd need some sort of level shifter at the feedback pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it possible to get that range?*

No, the lowest output voltage you can get is 2.5 V because that's the internal reference voltage which the chip uses to set the output voltage.

How do I know that?

Let's look at the Functional Block Diagram:

[image]

R1 and R2 form the feedback divide, the feedback signal goes into the chip via the FB pin and then goes into two comparators. The overvoltage comparator we can ignore, the **regulation comparator** is what is important. The reference input for this regulation comparator comes from the left, from pin SS where there's a capacitor to ground for the soft start. Then there's a NMOS switch to ground, a current source and a 2.5 V. That 2.5 V is the reference voltage.

When the chip operates, the NMOS switch to ground will be open, doing nothing. So the current source will charge the soft start capacitor to 2.5 V. So after startup there will be 2.5 V at the SS pin so there will be 2.5 V as well at the input of the regulation comparator.

The feedback loop then controls the system such that there will be 2.5 V at FB (on the right) as well. This is common to almost all (switched) regulators.

Also note that in the formula to calculate R1 and R2 from Vout (see section 8.2.2.1.1 on page 14) there's a 2.5 V in the formula.

If you want Vout = 2.5 V then R1/R2 = 0 so R1 = short and R2 = not placed.

If you want Vout < 2.5 V then you would need a resistor with a negative value! Obviously that is not a working solution.

Solutions do exist, a common one is to create a negative voltage (for example -2.5 V) and then use that as the negative supply rail for the chip.

Another solution is to use add an external circuit with an opamp which has inputs which can work down to GND voltage.

Both solutions aren't trivial, have issues of their own and are best left to experienced circuit designers.

If you want to learn more I suggest that you look at "lab supply" circuits as most lab supplies can go down to 0 V.

Comment: This only answers going to 0 and could you please add answer to this is it possible to get Vin == Vout, so at 6Vin to get 6Vout?

Comment: The datasheet does not answer that clearly but that's because this chip is not designed to be used that way. It **needs** a higher input voltage to operate properly. For Vout = 6 V my guess is that you need at least Vin = 7 V. Note how the numbers in the tables refer to the situation where Vin = 24 V which is what circuits like this need, a high input voltage and a much lower output voltage.

Comment: You're asking quite basic-level questions about a chip that is quite advanced-level. I predict that you will have issues using a complex chip like this. I strongly suggest that you look into buying a ready made module for your purposes. Search for "adjustable supply module 0V" on ebay.

Comment: Thank you for helping out!